# how to get cordova filetransfer parameters

Tags: asp.net, wcf, cordova, asmx, file-transfer

am using an asp.net website to receive files from a mobile device using Cordova 3.2.0 FileTransfer.upload command.
This can take parameters which are added to the options([see doco](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer))....so how do I get the parameters?
Tried using:

```
            Dim params As NameValueCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params
        UtilityManager.Log_Add("params count: " & params.Count)
        For Each key As String In params.AllKeys
            stmp = params.GetValues(key)
            For x As Integer = 0 To stmp.Length - 1
                UtilityManager.Log_Add("Key:" & key & " has value: " & stmp(x) & " at position: " & x)
            Next
        Next
```

but get none of my parameters, just the usual request parameters.
Tried the same thing on the Headers but the hosting site is using IIS6 and not in pieline mode so getting an error.

Originally tried WCF but for some reason it didn't like multi-part forms so I kept getting a File Not Found error in phonegap and it wouldn't even enter the function on the server. Could access the server function using Chrome Poster so don't know what is happening there.

Tested it on a aspx page and that worked so added an asmx service to do the work and it seems to be working fine with regards the file and options (except for the arguments). Maybe I should just put them through as querystrings (bad practice).

Trawled the web for a day to get the answer but it doesn't seem to be any out there....any suggestions?

Comment: Try searching in FormCollection its working for me in Asp.net WebApi

Comment: nope...no form fields....had to add them to the headers collection options.headers = {Data:["test","param"]} and collect them with the HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.getvalues("HTTP_DATA"). I'm using Cordova 3.2.0 so maybe there is a bug